# Check in - Check out process/version control for PSDs and Image files

Tags: image, version-control, psd, vcs-checkout

The title may not be so clear but the issue I am facing is this:

Are designers are working on large photoshop files across the network, this has a number of network traffic and file corruption issues which I am trying to overcome.

The way I want to do this is to have the designers copy the the files to their machine (Mac OSX) and work on them locally. But the problem then stands that they may forget to copy them back up or that another designer may start work on the version stored on the network.

What I need is a system where the designer checks out the files or folders from the server which locks those files so no other user can copy them until they are checked back in. We do not need to store revisions for the files.

My initial idea was to use SVN or preferably GIT and force lock on checkout somehow, does this sound feasible or is there a better system?

Comment: We resolved this using the app [layervault](http://layervault.com/) but thanks! We also stored finalised designs in the code repository before archiving.

Answer (score 0):

How big are the files on average? Not sure about GIT haven't used it but SVN should be ok - If you did go with SVN I would trial checking out over Http/Https vs Network Path to the repo as you may get a speed advantage out of one or the other. When we vpn to our repo at work it is literally 100 times faster over http than checking out using a network \\path to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

SVN is a good option, but you will have revisions (this is the whole point of SVN). SVN doesn't lock files by default, but you may configure it so that it does. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html?bcsi_scan_554E00F99A9AD604=0&bcsi_scan_filename=svn-book.html#svn.advanced.locking

I don't know git very well, but since it's not a centralized VCS, I'm pretty sure it isn't the right tool for your situation.